`std::sprintf` or `std::snprintf` with parameter pack without additional call and tmp buffer
Is there a way to get ride of the tmp and the second call to std::snprintf in Print? Can I do the same with just one std::snprintf call?
// arm-none-eabi-g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -Wall -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions

#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

void TransmitViaUartAndDma(const char * buffer, int len) {
  // "Embedded World"
  (void)buffer;
  (void)len;
}

constexpr std::size_t buf_size = 64; // = sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0])
std::array<char, buf_size> buffer{};

template<typename Arg, typename ...Args>
void Print(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args) {
  std::array<char, buf_size> tmp{};
  int len = std::snprintf(tmp.begin(), buffer.size(),
                                       "%s"
                                       "\n",
                                       std::forward<Arg>(arg));
  // std::printf("len = %d\n", len);
  len = std::snprintf(buffer.begin(), buffer.size(),
                                      tmp.cbegin(),
                                      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  // std::printf("len = %d\n", len);
  TransmitViaUartAndDma(buffer.cbegin(), len);
}

int main() {
  std::uint32_t val1{222};
  std::uint32_t val2{111};
  Print("%u. %u. Hello, ", val1, val2);
  // std::printf(buffer.cbegin());
  Print("%u. %u. World!", val2, val1);
  // std::printf(buffer.cbegin());
  return 0;
}

// 222. 111. Hello, 
// 111. 222. World!

Demo
Embedded
Note: I can't use std::cout.

If you have access to a C++23 capable compiler, then use std::println instead. Or std::format for C++20. Or the format library the standard is based on for older compilers.

And what is your assignment? What are its requirements? What are its limitations? And why do you need global variables, instead of returning values? And why std::array instead of std::string?

@Someprogrammerdude The buffer shall be transmitted via UART and DMA on a STM32L4 MCU, which means RAM and runtime (copying things around should be avoided) is a limiting factor. The compiler (IAR) only supports c++14 and open source is not allowed.

Since tmp is acting as the format string for the 2nd snprintf, the only way I can see to get rid of tmp (without re-writing the code to not use snprintf) is to move the \n character out of Print() and into the caller's format string, eg:
template<typename ...Args>
void Print(const char *format, Args&&... args) {
  int len = std::snprintf(buffer.begin(), buffer.size(),
                                       format,
                                       std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  // std::printf("len = %d\n", len);
  TransmitViaUartAndDma(buffer.cbegin(), len);
}

int main() {
  std::uint32_t val1{222};
  std::uint32_t val2{111};
  Print("%u. %u. Hello, \n", val1, val2);
  // std::printf(buffer.cbegin());
  Print("%u. %u. World!\n", val2, val1);
  // std::printf(buffer.cbegin());
  return 0;
}


UPDATE: as mentioned in a comment, you can alternatively just append the \n onto the end of the formatted buffer after snprintf exits, eg:
template<typename ...Args>
void Print(const char *format, Args&&... args) {
  int len = std::snprintf(buffer.begin(), buffer.size()-1,
                                       format,
                                       std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  buffer[len++] = '\n';
  // std::printf("len = %d\n", len);
  TransmitViaUartAndDma(buffer.cbegin(), len);
}

int main() {
  std::uint32_t val1{222};
  std::uint32_t val2{111};
  Print("%u. %u. Hello, ", val1, val2);
  // std::printf(buffer.cbegin());
  Print("%u. %u. World!", val2, val1);
  // std::printf(buffer.cbegin());
  return 0;
}


Appending \n at end of buffer might be a possibility: buffer[len] = '\n'; buffer[len + 1] = '\0'; (and adjusting parameter to buffer.size() - 1) (unless you consider it as rewrite without using snprintf).

@Jarod42 good point. Although, you don't need the null terminator since the length is being passing to TransmitViaUartAndDma()

Since this is an embedded system, the obvious solution is to get rid of all of the bloat libs. stdio.h is very inefficient (though not as inefficient as iostream) and also one of the most dangerous and poorly designed libraries in the history of programming.
Writing a bunch of integer to string routines manually isn't exactly rocket science and every seasoned dev got a bunch of those lying around from previous projects too. Why kill some kb of flash plus lots of RAM while at the same time introducing safety hazards. For something that just takes like 50-100 bytes of flash if hand-crafted. Example.
Or as in your example, if you are dealing with integer constants which are available at compile-time, then it's plain horrible to call a run-time conversion routine. Simply convert them at compile-time with stringification macros #define STR(x) #x. Or maybe some constexpr equivalent.

Thanks for the answer. The code shown above should deal as a minimum example. The values transmitted of the UART are in fact dynamic. Luckly (IMO), I don't need to deal with MISRA-C and I want to use std as much as I can. Anyway, I will check the hand-crafted example.

@ge45mue If possible, I'd stay away from standard libraries and C++ in general. STM32L4 got plenty of RAM compared to most microcontrollers, but I still wouldn't waste it just for the heck of it. Also the various std:: bloat libs may come with static storage duration classes or heap allocation, which are bad for multiple other reasons.
